# Open XML Extract Font Color From PPTx

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

I am trying to extract font color using open xml library but i also want to see which text the following color belongs.

Dim RGBColors_ As IEnumerable(Of A.RgbColorModelHex) = slide.Slide.Descendants(Of A.RgbColorModelHex)

```
            For Each clr In RGBColors_


                For Each detail_ In clr.Parent().ChildElements()
                    For Each colo In detail_.GetAttributes

                          **'HERE I GET THE COLOR CODE APPLIED**
                                 I NEED TEXT VALUE TOO? 

                    Next
                Next


            Next
```

I Can get the text value using ParagraphProperties or textproperty but i also want to combine RgbColorModelHex so that i can get paragraph , text and color in one function

Comment: Welcome to SO. You tagged `[c#]` but the code looks more like `[vb.net]`

Comment: You may consider downloading/installing the [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK#related-tools).